# Ошибка Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher

Tags: node.js, typescript

У меня есть .ts файл, который использует пакет puppeteer. Я могу запускать код с помощью пакета tsx, но не могу сбилдить .ts файл в .js файл. Я проверял, удалял полностью всё из tsconfig.json и при билде ничего не ломалось(ошибки не менялись). Как будто tsс вообще не видит tsconfig.json
При попытке сбилдить файл получается такая ошибка:

```
node_modules/puppeteer/lib/types.d.ts:31:5 - error TS18028:
Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher.
```

Как избавиться от этой ошибки? Ну или просто как сбилдить мне этот один .ts файл в .js файл.

Приложу конфиги:

tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "ES2022",
        "target": "ES2022",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "src/models",
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

---

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "sport-parsing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsx ./src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc ./src/index.ts --outDir ./dist"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^22.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.11.27",
    "pkg": "^5.8.1",
    "tsx": "^4.7.1",
    "typescript": "^5.4.2"
  }
}
```

Запускается на версии node.js v20.11.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было билдить проект командой просто tsc, а не `tsc ./src/index.ts --outDir ./dist`, что было у меня

Comment: `tsc -p tsconfig.json ...`

Comment: @nörbörnën я пытался так делать, но с другими ещё флагами. Оказалось, что если есть какие то другие флаги, то tsconfig.json игнорируется и выбирается конфигурация из данных флагов (кроме пути до tsconfig.json)